# OpenVDB file and Blender Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

i imported a open vdv file and render it but I looks blocky and has weird lines in the end render  I didn't change any settings from the volume, what can I do to make it, well not look like garbage
[image: the image]

Comment: where is the vdb from? What fields does it have?

Comment: what do you mean with fields ? I got the file from here https://jangafx.com/software/embergen/download/free-vdb-animations/

Comment: the gasoline explosion is the one I picked I saw a lot of tutorial using the exact same and in their videos it always looked great but not in my case im using 2.90.1 by the way

Comment: it has density flames and temperature if that's the field thing you mean

Comment: Yes that's what I was getting after. Those are important if you are trying to create a decent material for the vdb.

Comment: So the material could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases you should have at least some basic grids included to render a decent result. (Here I'm using a vdb I have on my system as an example, you should be able to follow along just fine)

- Firstly, check what grids you have available here:

[image]

- Second check the step size setting in the render section of the volume object. As it appears to currently be too coarse, try to lower it some. Perhaps it will help.
  See the documention on the [Volume Object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/volumes/introduction.html#introduction)

[image]

---

- Using the grids we have available, you can now build a nice material like this(based on your comments, this particular vdb has more grids available, so could have a more complex material if desired):
  [image]
  <sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>
- In this example, the render looks like this:

[image]

Comment: But I lowered the step size to .000001 and it still looks the exact same I don’t really now what else to change

Comment: Or am I lowering it to much ?

Comment: Nope this didn’t really change anything it still looks the exact same

Comment: Please help I didn’t fix it